# Spring MVC, control how JSON being converted to object

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a controller which handle '/sea/**' URLs,

when request with POST method to `/sea/**`, a JSON body will be like:

```
{
  "entities": [
    {
     "id" : "1",
     "name" : "foo"
    }
  ]
}
```

the java model is like this:

```
public class SEACreateRequest extends SEARequest{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6327746753793268966L;

    private List<Object> entities;

    public List<Object> getEntities() {
        return entities;
    }

    public void setEntities(List<Object> models) {
        this.entities = models;
    }
    
}
```

currently, jackson will convert entities to a list of java.util.Map.

the type of object in entities array is determined by concrete URL, for example if post to

/sea/user, it should be a User type, if post to /sea/car, it should be a Car Type, I have a

`URL -> type` mapping registry in memory, so how can I let spring convert the `entities` array to my actual types?

it's best to handle this at spring level, not on the level of jackson or Gson level.

I am using the newest spring boot 2.x. thanks !

Comment: You can keep `Car` and `User` as objects in `entities` Class , using `JsonIgnoreProperties` on top of class or by not specifying validation annotations , you can easily achieve, no need of mighty engineering here, if both are passed, both will be mapped to POJO !

Comment: @MuratYıldız Thanks for help, but I think you didn't get my idea here, it's not about just two types but any types

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to get Spring/Jackson to automatically deserialize arbitrary path-to-class combinations for you. I think you'll have to provide a generic controller/method and manually kick off deserialization by making a call yourself.

Comment: @dbreaux thanks, currently I am doing what you said, see my own answer, but for learning purpose, still looking for a solution by register a custom deserializer

Answer (score 0):

currently my solution is not let spring to deserialize json for me at all,

receive the json as string and deserialize it myself.

make SEACreateRequest generic:

```
public class SEACreateRequest<T> extends SEARequest {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6327746753793268966L;

    private List<T> entities;

    public List<T> getEntities() {
        return entities;
    }

    public void setEntities(List<T> models) {
        this.entities = models;
    }
    
}
```

then deserialize in controller like this:

```
@PostMapping("/**")                                                                                                            
public SEAResponse handleCreate(@RequestBody String reqJson) {                                                                 
    String locator = request.getRequestURI().replaceFirst("/sea/", "");                                                        
    log.info("----------【SEA创建-" + locator + "-开始】----------");                                                                
    try {                                                                                                                      
        Class<?> entityClz = registry.getMapper(locator).getEntityType();                                                      
        JavaType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(SEACreateRequest.class, entityClz);                    
        SEACreateRequest<?> req = mapper.readValue(reqJson, type);                                                             
        req.setLocator(locator);                                                                                               
        return handler.doCreate(req);                                                                                          
    } catch (Exception e) {                                                                                                    
        log.error("处理SEA创建请求失败：", e);                                                                                          
        return new SEAResponse(e);                                                                                             
    }                                                                                                                          
}
```